# JSON: Getting properties value in a list on a specific condition using c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a Jobject.

```
{
  "address": "test",
  "state": "",
  "postcode": "",
  "membergroup": {
    "User1": false,
    "User2": false,
    "User3": false,
    "User4": true,
    "User5": false,
    "User6": true
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the membergroup property value for all true values in a list of string using c#.

like {"user4","user6"}

Is this possible?
any suggestion of this please?

Comment: Where exactly is *"I am trying"* ? Show to us please.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can deserialize all **membergroup** values into an `array`  and pick the `true` values afterwards.

Comment: @ArthurRey .. i havent tried so far.. just checking is it possible or not? new to Json.net . yeah deserializing membergroup can do the job i think.i will check it.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use JObect if you don't want to have to create C# objects.

Note:
Serializing this back to a json string in the first step is probably not needed depending on how you are getting your json. It should already be coming in as a json string.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;



var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);

var entireJson = JToken.Parse(json);
var propertyList = (JObject)entireJson["membergroup"];

foreach (var property in propertyList)
{
    var key = property.Key;
    var value = (bool)property.Value;

    if (value)
    {
        key.Dump();
    }
}

//User4
//User6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Json.NET :

Create a class that will represent your json in C#:

```
public class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("membergroup")]
    public Dictionary<string, bool> MemberGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Get your json in a string, convert it to your c# class and pick only true values for your `membergroup`.

```
var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(jsonString);
entity.MemberGroup = entity.MemberGroup.Where(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: what is jsonString?i have a jobject do i need to convert/parse it to string ?

Comment: use jobject.ToString()